# android oval shape dialog

Tags: java, android

i have an application , it has a button , when pressed  it will fire a dialog with the default dialog shape , i wonder if i can change the default shape of dialog to an oval shape and also to apply special style to it ,

as explained in the images attached below :

**1- the Default Dialog Shape:**

[image]

**2-The Oval Dialog Shape (which i try to achieve):**

[image]

**my dialoge code :**

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);           
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

 TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
 text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_4)));

 ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
 image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic);

 Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);

 dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    dialog.show();
             }
        });

    }
```

**style code of default dialog:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">
     <stroke android:width="2dp" android:height="2dp" android:color="#B22222" /> 
       <solid android:color="#FCE6C9" /> 
        <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp"
         android:bottom="2dp" /> 
     <corners android:radius="5dp" /> 
    </shape>
```

i hope to have this done by code rather than using  9-patch image so it will be easy to control the dilaoge dimensions and adjust the text inside it as i neeed ,

**Any advice will be appreciated , thanks .**

Comment: Try to add the following to your dialog code:
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how to do this on android, but the approach I use in java is make the **JFrame** or **JDialog** rendered surface **transparent** and then draw my own custom shape inside. To make them transparent I use *AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity*

On this article you will find another ideas, like **capturing the desktop** before the frame or dialog is rendered and using it to patch your frame:

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/03/18/translucent-and-shaped-swing-windows.html

More information:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/

Here you have an implementation, not for android but it may help:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/shaped-transparent-jframe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Neat idea. On Android, to give an activity a transparent background, put this in your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Then, in your layout file for that activity, add this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/myImageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/myRoundBackground" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImageView"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
android:layout_margin="1dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Hello"
android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you can programmatically set the text on the TextView with the id myImageViewText .

Comment: i apply your code and add style to dialog but the result not as i need , even i cant control the text position

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [quick action menu totorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/). Try applying this tutorial with shape = oval background. I think you will get what you are trying to achieve.

---

Answer (score 0):

I think a transparent background with image sliced in oval for will work for you. and place the button to left of the oval image.

Answer (score 0):

THis method is similar to the one you are currently trying :
In your custom_dialog.xml give the relative layout an android:background="@drawable/ovaldialog" .

And in the ovaldialog.xml try giving the same parameters you are giving to edit the style by giving android:shape="oval" and also give the parameters to corners such as android:topLeftRadius="8dp" and android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" and play with those values until you get a desired kind of shape. To give the red color to the dialog give it a stroke of width 2/3dp and an android:color value.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks alot for your hint , it doesnt gave the full answer but direct me to solve my problem

Comment: If you want i can post the code too but i guess the answer was pretty self-explanatory . Glad i could help